# pure javascript equivalent of jquery $("#large_box2_link").click();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this small code within a jquery function, it works in every browser apart from ie6 and it just so happens our client only uses ie6,

Can anyone help me translate this into pure javascript?

```
$("#large_box2_link").click();
```

Comment: There's no reason that code shouldn't work in IE6. There's likely something else going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("large_box2_link").click();
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, i know it was a very noobish question but i'm more of a front end html css man with some jquery kind of person, your code worked, thanks allot

Comment: No problem, funtymeeee. All questions welcomed :) I was once where you are with respects to javascript, and someday it will all be common knowledge to you ;)